# Laravel difference between DB::raw and selectRaw

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I run the following code I correctly get the sum of points appended.

```
User::withCount([
    'points' => function ($q) {
        $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(points)"));
    },
])
```

But when I use `selectRaw("SUM(points)")` instead of `select(DB::raw("SUM(points)"))`, Laravel returns the count of rows, not the sum. It's as if the function is not being run at all. What gives?

Here's the MySQL queries made by Eloquent

```
  #With DB::raw
    "select `users`.*, (select SUM(points) from `user_points` where `users`.`user-id` = `user_points`.`user-id`) as `points_count` 
    from `users` 
    order by `points_count` desc"

    #With selectRaw
    "select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `user_points` where `users`.`user-id` = `user_points`.`user-id`) as `points_count` 
    from `users` 
    order by `points_count` desc"
```

**Why do `DB::raw` and `selectRaw` return different results with the example above?**

Comment: Log both queries with `\DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`. Are they different?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes. Added the queries to the question, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You get different queries because `select()` *replaces* the selected columns, while `selectRaw()` *adds* a selected column.

So `select(DB::raw('SUM(points)'))` replaces the default `count(*)`.

Comment: Ok - and I can't add a column in `withCount` so that's why Laravel isn't processing it right?

Answer (score 1):

They are almost the same but `selectRaw` allows bindings. looking at the source code:

```
// Line 232, /Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
public function selectRaw($expression, array $bindings = [])
{
    $this->addSelect(new Expression($expression));
    if ($bindings) {
        $this->addBinding($bindings, 'select');
    }
    return $this;
}

// Line 835 /Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
public function raw($value)
{
    return new Expression($value);
}
```

Based on the method signatures

```
// You can do bindings with selectRaw()
->selectRaw('complex_thing(column_name, ?)', [123]);

// but there's not a way to do bindings with DB::raw()
->select(DB::raw('no_bindings_allowed('fixed', 'values', 42)');
```

You can manually insert a value into the `DB::raw()` string above, but you need to validate to make sure that code injection is not possible. Hope you can understand.

Comment: Very cool that you reached into the query builder to show the code, thank you! Still I don't get why Laravel returns a different result based on the example in my question.

Comment: Have you tried `selectRaw(DB::raw("SUM(points)"))`. It will give you the sum.